# MFC CEdit Control does not handle Key Pressed after added to Accelerator

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, treeview, editbox

I have a Problem with the `del` Key in my MFC Application.

I have defined an Accelerator entry to use the `del` key in my `CTreeView.`

My Application uses a split view. The `CTreeView` is on the left panel and the `CEdit` Control is on the right Panel inside a `CFormView`.

The Entry is defined like this:

```
VK_DELETE,      ID_EDIT_DELETE,         VIRTKEY, NOINVERT
```

The `ID_EDIT_DELETE` event is handled inside the `CTreeView`.

After i added it, the `del` Key stopped working inside the `CEdit` Controls.

What do I have to do to restore the functionality in CEdit Control?
Do i have to add something like:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_DELETE, &StationView::OnDelete)
```

to every Panel which contains an `CEdit Control`? And then manually implement the delete Character Functionality?
Or is there an easier way to pass the `del` Key event to the `CEdit` Control?

UPDATE:

I overwrote the `PreTranslateMessage` Method inside the `CFormView` Class and the Del Key Press gets catched. But  how do i proceed further?

UPDATE V2:

As asked here the Code for the Splitter Creation:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT /*lpcs*/, CCreateContext* pContext) {

    // create splitter window
    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftView), CSize(250, 1000), pContext) ||
        !m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLineSyncView), CSize(500, 1000), pContext)) {
        m_wndSplitter.DestroyWindow();
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Where is your CEdit control? Does it belong to the Tree?

Comment: I use a splitter panel so the tree view is on the left panel and the edit controls are on the right panel. I have updated the question.

Comment: I overwrote the PreTranslateMessage Method inside the CFormView Class and the Del Key Press gets catched. But how do i proceed further?

Comment: Can you add some code how you create the splitter view?

Comment: Added the Code to the Question.

Comment: WM_GETDLGCODE message can be handled for the CEdit with DLGC_WANTALLKEYS flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/145/Q145616/):

> MFC has default implementation for menu handlers and accelerator keys
>   that AppWizard adds to your application to handle these functions.
>   These menu handlers get the accelerator keystrokes instead of your
>   edit control.

The solution is to load the accelerator table and send the message to your edit control in case it's needed.

Here is the code:

1. In your `CFormView` derived class, add `HACCEL m_hAccelTable` member.
2. Load the accelerator in overridden `OnInitialUpdate`:

   ```
   void CFormRight::OnInitialUpdate()
   {
       CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();

       m_hAccelTable = ::LoadAccelerators(AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));
   }
   ```
3. Override the `PreTranslateMessage` function in your `CFormView` derived class.
   We need to check there if this is a key message, if the focused window is edit control and if the has an accelerator.

   ```
   BOOL CFormRight::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
   {
       if (m_hAccelTable)
       {
           // cheaper to check the message range then TranslateAccelerator
           if (WM_KEYFIRST <= pMsg->message && pMsg->message <= WM_KEYLAST)
           {
               CWnd* pWnd = GetFocus();
               if (IsEdit(pWnd) && ::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd, m_hAccelTable, pMsg))
               {
                   pWnd->SendMessage(pMsg->message, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);
                   return FALSE;
               }
           }
       }
       return CFormView::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);    
   }

   BOOL CFormRight::IsEdit(CWnd* pWnd)
   {
       ASSERT(pWnd != NULL);
       HWND hWnd = pWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
       if (hWnd == NULL)
           return FALSE;

       TCHAR szClassName[6];
       return ::GetClassName(hWnd, szClassName, 6) &&
           _tcsicmp(szClassName, _T("Edit")) == 0;
   }
   ```
4. Finally, destroy the accelerator.

   ```
   void CFormRight::OnDestroy()
   {
       CFormView::OnDestroy();

       ::DestroyAcceleratorTable(m_hAccelTable);   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to handle ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI:

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_EDIT_DELETE, &StationView::OnDelete)
```

and

```
void StationView::OnDelete(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    // TODO: Add your command update UI handler code here

    pCmdUI->Enable(! IsEdit(GetFocus())); // see previous post for IsEdit method
}
```

However, I didn't tried this. You try :)

P.S. How to implement IsEdit (taken from previous post):

```
BOOL CFormRight::IsEdit(CWnd* pWnd)
{
    ASSERT(pWnd != NULL);
    HWND hWnd = pWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    if (hWnd == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    TCHAR szClassName[6];
    return ::GetClassName(hWnd, szClassName, 6) &&
        _tcsicmp(szClassName, _T("Edit")) == 0;
}
```